# Scanf while loop affecting the next scanf outside of the loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf

My test input is

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
[9,9]
```

Or it could be any number of 3d coordinates before a single 2d coordinate, my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int z1;
    int x2;
    int y2;


    while(scanf("[%d,%d,%d]\n", &x1,&y1,&z1) == 3){
        printf("(x,y,z) --->  (%d,%d,%d)\n", x1,y1,z1);
    }



    scanf("[%d,%d]", &x2, &y2);
    printf("(%d,%d)\n", x2, y2);

    return 0;
}
```

If I change the while loop to three separate scanfs then it works fine, but the problem is that I don't know how many I will need. Is there anyway to fix this so the 2d coordinate gets scanned?

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `fgets` to capture input. `sscanf` is one means to parse the input.
An advantage is the input may be parsed multiple times and the input stream is cleared up to the trailing newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void){
    char line[256] = "";
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int z1;
    int x2;
    int y2;

    while( fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        if ( 3 == sscanf ( line, "[%d,%d,%d]", &x1, &y1, &z1)) {
            printf ( "(x,y,z) --->  (%d,%d,%d)\n", x1,y1,z1);
        }
        else if ( 2 == sscanf ( line, "[%d,%d]", &x2, &y2)) {
            printf ( "(x,y) --->  (%d,%d)\n", x2, y2);
            break;//exit the while loop
        }
        else {
            printf ( "input coordinates [x,y,z] or [x,y]\n");
            printf ( "try again\n");
        }
    }
```